# LeetCode problem 2503 Python optimization

Tags: python, matrix, hashset, breadth-first-search, heap

I was trying to solve [problem 2503](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-number-of-points-from-grid-queries/) on LeetCode using Python. I came up with a solution using breadth-first search and a min-heap. However, I ran into time complexity issues with a version of my code. I was able to complete the test cases with a different version, but I am trying to figure out why the newer version is faster than the previous version I had used.

For reference, this is the previous version:

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush

class Solution:
    def maxPoints(self, grid: List[List[int]], queries: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        m = len(grid)
        n = len(grid[0])
        answer = [0 for _ in range(len(queries))]
        s_ind = sorted(range(len(queries)), key = queries.__getitem__)
        frontier = [(grid[0][0], 0, 0)]
        visited = set()

        for s in s_ind:
            q = queries[s]

            while frontier:
                val, i, j = frontier[0]

                if val >= q:
                    break

                heappop(frontier)
                visited.add((i, j))
                
                if i > 0 and (i - 1, j) not in visited:
                    up = (grid[i - 1][j], i - 1, j)
                    heappush(frontier, up)
                if i < m - 1 and (i + 1, j) not in visited:
                    down = (grid[i + 1][j], i + 1, j) 
                    heappush(frontier, down)
                if j > 0 and (i, j - 1) not in visited:
                    left = (grid[i][j - 1], i, j - 1)
                    heappush(frontier, left)
                if j < n - 1 and (i, j + 1) not in visited:
                    right = (grid[i][j + 1], i, j + 1)
                    heappush(frontier, right)
                
            answer[s] = len(visited)
        
        return answer
```

This is the newer version:

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush

class Solution:
    def maxPoints(self, grid: List[List[int]], queries: List[int]) -> List[int]:
        m = len(grid)
        n = len(grid[0])
        answer = [0 for _ in range(len(queries))]
        s_ind = sorted(range(len(queries)), key = queries.__getitem__)
        frontier = [(grid[0][0], 0, 0)]
        count = 0

        for s in s_ind:
            q = queries[s]

            while frontier:
                val, i, j = frontier[0]

                if val >= q:
                    break

                heappop(frontier)
                grid[i][j] = None
                count += 1
                
                if i > 0 and grid[i - 1][j] != None:
                    up = (grid[i - 1][j], i - 1, j)
                    heappush(frontier, up)
                    grid[i - 1][j] = None
                if i < m - 1 and grid[i + 1][j] != None:
                    down = (grid[i + 1][j], i + 1, j) 
                    heappush(frontier, down)
                    grid[i + 1][j] = None
                if j > 0 and grid[i][j - 1] != None:
                    left = (grid[i][j - 1], i, j - 1)
                    heappush(frontier, left)
                    grid[i][j - 1] = None
                if j < n - 1 and grid[i][j + 1] != None:
                    right = (grid[i][j + 1], i, j + 1)
                    heappush(frontier, right)
                    grid[i][j + 1] = None
                
            answer[s] = count
        
        return answer
```

Basically, both solutions are pretty much the same, except the old solution (which has runtime issues) uses a set to manage visited cells in the matrix, while the newer solution just sets visited cells to None.

From my understanding, both implementations should have the same runtime complexity (`O(1)`) for specifying that or checking if a node has been visited. Besides this, all other functionalities are implemented in the exact same way. Why, then, is the new approach considerably faster than the old one?

I had suspected that the implementation with sets was slower due to collisions. However, from my research and also based on the bounds of the problem parameters, it seems like we should not need to worry about collisions. These were the bounds specified for the parameters:

- `m == grid.length`
- `n == grid[i].length`
- `2 <= m, n <= 1000`
- `4 <= m * n <= 10^5`
- `k == queries.length`
- `1 <= k <= 10^4`
- `1 <= grid[i][j], queries[i] <= 10^6`

I also crossed out the possibility of computing `len(visited)` to be the issue, since this should also be `O(1)`.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. Aside from that, you are required to explain the problem (what happens when you try running that minimal reproducible example? What should happen instead, and how is that different?) **in the question itself, not** by linking to an outside site.

Comment: "Why, then, is the new approach considerably faster than the old one?" - just to make sure: you *do* understand that "O(1)" only describes how the runtime *grows as problem size increases*, and tells *nothing* about the actual amount of time taken, right? Anyway, it's not reasonable to show others two separate examples of dozens of lines of code each, and expect them to immediately see what's changed between them.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes I understand this. And I expect the newer one to be faster no doubt. But what I am wondering is if there is some sort of underlying time complexity disparity that leads to the old implementation having timeout issues but the newer succeeding fine.